# XML output is truncated in a file, but not in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

After referring to those two posts - 
[XML Output is Truncated in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742651/xml-output-is-truncated-in-sql), [Generating an XML output using XML OPTIONS in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52694781/generating-an-xml-output-using-xml-options-in-sql-server)

And setting in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) as -
[Option Setting in SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYvFE.png) to set XML output data to an unlimited size.

```
DECLARE @xmldata xml
SET @xmldata = (
SELECT 
'DATE' as 'column/@name', [DATE] as 'column', null, 
'ID' as 'column/@name', [ID] as 'column', null, 
'NAME' as 'column/@name', [NAME] as 'column', null
FROM TEST_TBL
FOR XML PATH('row'), ROOT('resultset')
)
SELECT @xmldata AS returnXML
```

The XML output in SSMS is all right.
But if I run SQLCMD.EXE to generate an XML output file as below,

```
DECLARE @xmldata xml
SET @xmldata = (
SELECT 
'DATE' as 'column/@name', [DATE] as 'column', null, 
'ID' as 'column/@name', [ID] as 'column', null, 
'NAME' as 'column/@name', [NAME] as 'column', null
FROM TEST_TBL
FOR XML PATH('row'), ROOT('resultset')
)
SELECT @xmldata AS returnXML
:OUT abc.XML
GO
```

The output file - abc.XML is truncated at the length of 1,048,578 in a single row.

Is there any way to set the XML output file - abc.XML to an 'Unlimited' size as in SSMS?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: SQL-Server is very limited when you need interaction with the file system. I prefer [bulk copy utility BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) for such issues...

Comment: @Shnugo, thanks for your very useful tip. I'll give a try.

Comment: @Shnugo, after several trials, BCP works for me now. Thanks for your very helpful tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(4000), @AUTCMD VARCHAR(4000), @XMLCMD VARCHAR(4000)
SET @Path = 'YourPathHere'
SET @AUTCMD = 'net use ' + @Path + ' YourPasswordHere /USER:YourUserNameHere' 
SET @XMLCMD = 'bcp "DECLARE @xmldata xml SET @xmldata = (SELECT ''DATE'' as ''column/@name'', [DATE] as ''column'', null, ''ID'' as ''column/@name'', [ID] as ''column'', null, ''NAME'' as ''column/@name'', [NAME] as ''column'', null FROM TEST_TBL FOR XML PATH(''row''), ROOT(''resultset'')) SELECT @xmldata AS returnXML" queryout "' + @Path + '\abc.XML" -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -T -c'


exec xp_cmdshell @AUTCMD
exec xp_cmdshell @XMLCMD
```